# Padding for WinForms TreeView

Tags: winforms, treeview, invisible

In a WinForms application I have a custom button positioned on top of a TreeView. In certain scenarios the button will hide the bottom content from the TreeView:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to invisibly inflate the TreeView-height in the bottom in order to trigger the scroll bar earlier, and am open for other suggestions, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing with buttons at the top:

[image: TreeView with buttons]

I used a `UserControl` with a `TreeView` docked to fill and a `Panel` docked to the top. (In your case, dock the panel to the bottom.) I set `TreeView.BorderStyle = None` and used another `Panel` to look like a border with 1px padding all around, which hosts the button panel and tree. You can make the tree `public` or expose it via a property. With docking you can also hide the button panel as necessary, and the tree will automatically take up the remaining space. I also used a `Label` docked to the bottom inside the button panel to act as a visual separator.

Comment: Your solution looks smooth, thank you for your suggestion! However I wanted to avoid "filling up" the height of my button with a panel I don't know what to use for. & the tree will still look cut where the panel begins.